# Filtering query based on parentIds from another table using Contains()

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I'm getting error which is saying Message

> The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a
>   maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend
>   the request.

I am trying to get the students' gender from another table. After selecting *parentIds* of the students' gender filtered I have used `Contains()`.

```
var studentGender = StudentService.Service
                                  .StudentParents
                                  .AsQueryable()
                                  .Where(sp => sp.gender == gender)
                                  .Select(sp => sp.parentId)
                                  .ToList();

 query = query.Where(p => studentGender.Contains(p.parentId));
```

If I have parentIds count less than 2100 it works fine with no issue but I have a clients which has more parentIds getting back and then as a result it does not fetch and throws error.

Comment: You will need to rethink your query, maybe a join will work better for you, and pushing the whole query to the DB at once

Comment: Exactly - why are you instantiating `studentGender` with `ToList` on the client? What happens if you leave off `ToList`?